# If I have that $\limsup_{n}E|X_n|^{r} \leq E|X|^{r}$, is that enough to show that $\{|X_n|^{r}:n\geq 1\}$ is uniformly integrable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

If I have that $\limsup_{n}E|X_n|^{r} \leq E|X|^{r}$, is that enough to show that $\{|X_n|^{r}:n\geq 1\}$ is uniformly integrable? I am not sure here if the limsup condition here is as strong as if I had a uniformly bound. Does anyone have any hints as to how I can work with such a definition? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's enough. Remember that $\limsup_n a_n = \lim_n\{\sup_{k\ge n} a_k\}$ for any sequence $\{a_n\}$ of real numbers. If the limsup is bounded above by some $A$, then there exists $N$ such that
$$
\sup_{k\ge N} a_k \le A +1.
$$
But this implies that $a_k\le A +1$ for all $k\ge N$ ( since the sup is an upper bound on every term ), so $A+1$ is a uniform bound on $a_k$ when $k\ge N$. For $k<N$, we have the bound
$$a_k \le \max\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{N-1}\}.$$
The max of the above two bounds is a uniform bound for every $a_k$.

In short, we've proved that only finitely many terms of a sequence will exceed the limsup + 1 of that sequence.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if what you have here is a uniform bound or showing uniform integrability. Does the uniform bound you have show uniform integrability?

Comment: @user136503 The argument above shows that $\sup_n E(|X_n|^r)<\infty$, which is sufficient to conclude (if $r>1$) that the collection $\{X_n\}$ are uniformly integrable. It's not enough to conclude that the collection $\{|X_n|^r\}$ are UI.

Comment: Thanks, when you create the bound of the maximum for $k < N$, is it possible one of the $a_i$ from $i=1,\ldots,N-1$ could be infinite?

Comment: @user136503 Yes. That would be possible if $E(|X_i|^r)$ is infinite for some $i$.

Comment: If one of them were infinite, would that affect the bound you have?

Comment: If one of the $E(|X_i|^r)$ were infinite then the sup over all $i$ has to be infinite ... there's no way to avoid that. But if the limsup is finite, you can just ignore the terms where $i<N$ -- the remaining terms $\{X_k\}_{k\ge N}$ will form a UI collection, which is all you need to apply whatever theorem is expecting your collection to be UI.

Answer (score 1):

Define $Y_n:=\left|X_n\right|^r$ and $Y:=\left|X\right|^r$. If $\limsup_n\mathbb E[Y_n]\leqslant E[Y]$, it may be not true that $\mathbb E[Y_n]$ is finite for each $n$. Even if it is the case, the best we can deduce is that $\sup_n\mathbb E\left[Y_n\right]$ is finite (see grand_chat's answer). But this is not enough for the uniform integrability, for example if $Y_n=n\mathbf 1_{(0,1/N)}$ on the unit interval endowed with Lebesgue measure.